# Gap at top of screen in production, but not in development

Tags: android, react-native, expo, mobile-development

I'm building a React Native app using Expo.
In production, there's a gap at the top of the screen that isn't present in development. Why is this happening? At the moment, this problem has only presented on android devices - I don't have an iOS version, so I don't know if it's an issue on iPhones too. Following screenshot shows the gap as a white space at the top of the screen:


[image]

This gap is present at the top of every page/screen in the app, so I suspect there's something wrong in how I've configured my stack navigation:

**homeStack.tsx**

```
import { useContext,useEffect } from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import List from '../screens/List'
import Map from '../screens/Map'
import GigDetails from "../screens/GigDetails";
import Register from "../screens/Register";
import RegistrationSuccess from "../screens/RegistrationSuccess";
import Profile from "../screens/Profile";
import Login from "../screens/Login";
import EditDetails from "../screens/EditDetails";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import HeaderProfile from "../components/HeaderProfile";
import type { NativeStackScreenProps } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import About from "../screens/About";
import { AuthContext } from "../AuthContext";


export interface Time {
  nanoseconds:number
  seconds:number;
}

export interface GigObject {
  tickets:string,
  venue:string,
  dateAndTime: Time,
  isFree:boolean,
  image:string,
  genre: string,
  gigName:string,
  blurb:string,
  id?:string,
  ticketPrice?:string,
  address:string,
  links: string[],
  gigName_subHeader:string,
  location?:{longitude:number,latitude:number},
}

export interface UserDetails {
  firstName:string,
  lastName:string,
  UID:string
}


export type RootStackParamList = {
  Map:undefined,
  List:undefined,
  GigDetails: GigObject,
  About:undefined,
  Register:undefined, 
  RegistrationSuccess:undefined,
  Profile:undefined,
  Login:undefined,
  EditDetails:UserDetails,
  Header:undefined
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>()

export type listProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'List', 'MyStack'>
export type mapProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Map', 'MyStack'>
export type gigDetailsProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'GigDetails', 'MyStack'>
export type registerProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Register', 'MyStack'>
export type registrationSuccessProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'RegistrationSuccess', 'MyStack'>
export type profileProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Profile', 'MyStack'>
export type loginProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Login', 'MyStack'>
export type editDetailsProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'EditDetails', 'MyStack'>



export const MyStack = () => {

  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext)

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Map"
    >
      <Stack.Screen 
      name="Map" 
      component={Map} 
      options={{
        title:'',
        headerTitle: () => <Header/>,
        // headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        headerStyle:{
          backgroundColor:'#377D8A',
        }
    }}     
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
      name="List" 
      component={List} 
      options={{
        title: '',
        // headerTitle: () => <Header/>,
        // headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        headerStyle:{
          backgroundColor:'#F7F6F5'
        }
    }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
      name="GigDetails" 
      component={GigDetails} 
      options={{
        title:'',
        // headerTitle: () => <Header/>,
        // headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        headerStyle:{
          backgroundColor:'#4ACCD5'
        }
    }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
      name="About" 
      component={About} 
      options={{
        title: '',
        headerStyle:{
          backgroundColor:'#F7F6F5'
        }
    }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
      name="Register" 
      component={Register} 
      options={{
        title:'',
        headerStyle:{
          backgroundColor:'#F7F6F5'
        }
    }}
    />
      <Stack.Screen 
      name="EditDetails" 
      component={EditDetails} 
      options={{
        title:'',
        headerStyle:{
          backgroundColor:'#E2DBCF'
        }
    }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen 
    name="RegistrationSuccess" 
    component={RegistrationSuccess} 
    options={{
      title:'',
      headerStyle:{
        backgroundColor:'#F7F6F5'
      },
      headerLeft: () => {return null}
  }}
      />
  {user ? (
          <Stack.Screen 
          name="Profile" 
          component={Profile} 
          options={{
            title:'',
            headerTitle: () => <HeaderProfile/>,
            headerStyle:{
              backgroundColor:'#377D8A'
            }
        }}
        />
   ): null}
    <Stack.Screen 
    name="Login" 
    component={Login} 
    options={{
      title:'',
      headerStyle:{
        backgroundColor:'#F7F6F5'
      },
  }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

And here's the header element I'm using on some of my screens:

**Header.tsx**

```
import { FC, useContext, useEffect,useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { RootStackParamList } from "../routes/homeStack";
import { StackNavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { AuthContext } from "../AuthContext";
import { useGetUser } from "../hooks/useGetUser";


const Header: FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, "Map">>();


  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const userDetails = useGetUser(user?.uid);
  const { firstName } = userDetails || {};



  const content = user && userDetails ? (

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Profile")}>
      <View style = {styles.profile}>
        <Ionicons name="ios-person-outline" size={24} color="white" />
        <Text style = {styles.firstName}>{firstName}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>

  ) : (

    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Login")}
        style={styles.button}
      >
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Register")}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText_register}>Sign up</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>

  )


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        {content}
    </View>
  );
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    flexDirection: "column",
    width: 45,
    height: 25,
    marginRight: 10,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 8,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: "#377D8A",
    textAlign: "center",
    fontFamily: "NunitoSans",
    fontSize: 12,
    lineHeight: 22,
  },
  buttonText_register: {
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    fontFamily: "NunitoSans",
    fontSize: 12,
    lineHeight: 22,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    width: "100%",
  },
  firstName: {
    fontFamily: "LatoRegular",
    color:'white'
  },
  profile: {
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    width: "100%",
  },
});

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some wild problems with formatting the Status Bar on Android as well as on iOS. To dodge these problems, you can use the `expo-status-bar`-Component. You can find the full documentation here: [Status Bar Documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/status-bar/)

Just install the package if you don't have it: `npm install expo-status-bar`

Afterwards add this line of code **above** your `Stack.Navigator` in `homeStack.tsx`:

```
return (
    <StatusBar style="auto" />  // <-- add this line
    <Stack.Navigator
    ...
```

There are of course more styling options available (see documentation), but this should at least adjust the background color to your apps background.